# change the value of every object in an array if 0 to null

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have this for example:

```
const sample = [
  { id: 1, val1: 0, val4: 10 },
  { id: 10, val1: 1, val4: 10, val19: 0, val29: 0 },
  { id: 11, val1: 0, val4: 0, val19: 0, val29: 10 },
];
```

and I want to change every 0 value into null

```
const sample = [
  { id: 1, val1: null, val4: 10 },
  { id: 10, val1: 1, val4: 10, val19: null, val29: null },
  { id: 11, val1: null, any: null, sample: null, val29: 10 },
];
```

I know I need to use `map` but I'm having difficulty in accessing every object.

Comment: by ```value``` do you mean val1, val2, etc...?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have no methods this might work too.

You stringify it and use an replacer function to replace all zeros to `null`. Then just parse it back.

Works for deeper nested objects aswell

```js
const sample = [
  { id: 1, val1: 0, val4: 10 },
  { id: 10, val1: 1, val4: 10, val19: 0, val29: 0 },
  { id: 11, val1: 0, val4: 0, val19: 0, val29: 10 },
];

let str = JSON.stringify(sample,(k, v) =>  v === 0 ? null : v);
let result = JSON.parse(str);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to do loop through the list and then for every property in the object you check for **val**

```js
const sample = [
  { id: 1, val1: 0, val4: 10 },
  { id: 10, val1: 1, val4: 10, val19: 0, val29: 0 },
  { id: 11, val1: 0, val4: 0, val19: 0, val29: 10 },
];

let sample1 = sample[0]; //<<-- you may loop through your entire array

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(sample1)) {
  if (key.lastIndexOf('val')>=0 && value === 0){
       sample1[key] = null;
   }
}

console.log(sample1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need forEach if you do not want a new array

```js
const sample = [ { id: 1, val1: 0, val4: 10 }, { id: 10, val1: 1, val4: 10, val19: 0, val29: 0 }, { id: 11, val1: 0, val4: 0, val19: 0, val29: 10 }];

sample.forEach(item => { 
  for (val in item) item[val] = item[val] === 0 ? null : item[val] 
});
console.log(sample)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, but you need `let` to reuse the variable name

```js
let sample = [
  { id: 1, val1: 0, val4: 10 },
  { id: 10, val1: 1, val4: 10, val19: 0, val29: 0 },
  { id: 11, val1: 0, val4: 0, val19: 0, val29: 10 },
];
sample = sample.map(obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    obj[key] = obj[key] || null;
  });
  return obj;
});

console.log(sample)
```

This is basically getting the keys of each object then checking value of object against that key in `obj[key] = obj[key] || null`. So when `obj[key]` will be either 0, null or undefined, it will become equal to null, otherwise it won't update.

Comment: I made you a snippet. I also removed the unnecessary spread [...] - lastly, you will set `valx: ""` to null too with your falsy shortcut. Otherwise shorter code than mine

Comment: @mplungjan thanks. I thought using `Object.keys(obj)` directly would not work, so I used the spread operator.

Answer (score 0):

This is what `Array.prototype.map` was made for, it takes a function as a parameter, that is called once for each element of the array, while providing the element itself as an argument. The.map function returns a new set and does not directly modify the original. Whatever the return value is for the parameter function for each element is, becomes the new value of that element in the newly constructed array.

In your case though it is a bit more complicated since each element itself is an object, so we can convert each object to an array, map is own properties, and return the reconstructed object to our main .maps parameter function

So..

```
sample=sample.map(function (currentElement){
    return (typeof(currentElement) == "object" ?
        Object.fromEntries(
            Object.entries(
                currentElement
            ).map(function (prop){
                return prop === 0 ? null : prop
            })
        ) : currentElement
    )
})
```

Comment: No it is not necessarily what map was made for since map will return a NEW array and is not needed if you just want to modify the existing array, then that is what forEach was made for. Your code is very complex for a very simple task

Comment: @mplungjan ok how can it be simpler?

Comment: @mplugjan i see my own

Comment: `sample.forEach(item => {  for (val in item) item[val] = item[val] === 0 ? null : item[val] });` is simpler than yours no?

Answer (score 0):

I have an solution using map only, may help:

```js
var sample = [
    { id: 1, val1: 0, val4: 10 },
    { id: 10, val1: 1, val4: 10, val19: 0, val29: 0 },
    { id: 11, val1: 0, val4: 0, val19: 0, val29: 10 },
  ]; 
var output = sample.map((item) => {
      Object.keys(item).map((key) => {
        item[key] = (item[key] == 0 ? null : item[key]); return item[key]
      });
      return item;
  });
  
  console.log(output);
```

Comment: This is identical to more than one other answer here

Comment: Agree, it's with a little different approach, right?

Comment: Yes, needless use of {} and () ;)

Comment: Yes I can remove

Answer (score 0):

You can use "for...in" to access every object

[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/lorrylockie/n35L2z6u/2/)

```js
const sample = [
  { id: 1, val1: 0, val4: 10 },
  { id: 10, val1: 1, val4: 10, val19: 0, val29: 0 },
  { id: 11, val1: 0, val4: 0, val19: 0, val29: 10 },
];

sample.map((s) => {
  for (let i in s) if (s[i] === 0) s[i] = null;
  return s;
});
console.log(sample);
```

Comment: Why use map and not forEach. You do not need the array map creates

Comment: You also do not need to return anything: `sample.forEach(s => { for (let i in s) if (s[i] === 0) s[i] = null; });
`

Answer (score 0):

### Immutable Style

```js
const sample: Record<string, unknown>[] = [
  { id: 1, val1: 0, val4: 10 },
  { id: 10, val1: 1, val4: 10, val19: 0, val29: 0 },
  { id: 11, val1: 0, val4: 0, val19: 0, val29: 10 }
]

const updated = sample.map((rec) =>
  Object.keys(rec).reduce<Record<string, unknown>>(
    (acc, key) => (rec[key] == 0 ? { ...acc, [key]: null } : { ...acc, [key]: rec[key] }),
    {}
  )
)

console.log(updated)
// OUTPUT
// [
//   { id: 1, val1: null, val4: 10 },
//   { id: 10, val1: 1, val4: 10, val19: null, val29: null },
//   { id: 11, val1: null, val4: null, val19: null, val29: 10 }
// ]
```